# CKEditor 5 - Toggle between dark and light theme/background for the editor on external action/event

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor5 in a React app and trying to implement a toggle to switch between dark and light theme for CKEditor5.

From their documentation I came across this: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html

The documentation mainly describes styling the editor theme from scratch and building the ckeditor package which essentially defines the default style theme for the editor.

**But what I'm trying to figure out is a way to manipulate the editor background and plugins color via. CSS on-the-fly based on event trigger (when user toggles the UI theme for the entire site via. toggle button) i.e. toggling between light and dark theme for the editor.** Is there any way/pointers on how this can be done?

Right now, in my React component I invoke the CKEditor component in the following way to render it on the UI:

```
      <div>
        <CKEditor
          editor={Editor}
          config={editorConfiguration}
          disabled={isReadOnlyMode}
          data={fieldValue}
          onReady={(editor) => {
            if (isReadOnlyMode) {
              const toolbarElement = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element;
              toolbarElement.style.display = "none";
            }
          }}        
        />
      </div>
```